# (Python) number of list's element

Tags: python

```
print(circles)
```

output

```
[[[282 132 121]
  [712 380 121]
  [280 628 121]
  [138 380 122]
  [570 132 121]
  [568 628 120]]]
```

I want to reach number of list's element = 6

```
 print(len(circles)) # gives me "1"
```

Comment: `len(circles[0])`

Comment: try: `print(len(circles[0]))` you have list in a list

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are `len`ing your list inside a list. List is `[this]`.

You have `outer_list[ inner_list[ small_list_with_numbers[123 123 123] ] ]`, thus `len(circles)` is `len(outer_list)` which is 1 - only 1 inner list there.

Either do `len(circles[0])` == 6, or get rid of outer list somewhere else.